# PhantomJS turning characters into bad data

Tags: javascript, utf-8, character-encoding, phantomjs

I am running a js file in phantomjs

```
var settings = {mode: 'w', charset: 'UTF-8'};
page.open(path, settings, function (status) {
    if (status !== "success") {
        console.log("Unable to access network");
    } else {
        page.evaluate(function() {
            window.console.log = function(msg) { alert(msg) }; 
            var $p = document.querySelectorAll('.my-class')[0];
            var html = $p.innerHTML;
            return html;
        });
    }
});
```

The data looks like

```
<div class="my-class">Power, speed, style —&nbsp;James Bond’s 10&nbsp;greatest drives</div>
```

But the returned html from phantomJS is

```
Power, speed, style ΓÇö James BondΓÇÖs 10 greatest drives
```

My page has

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

in the head.

Comment: What about file encoding?

Comment: The website is an aspx file that renders many html files inside of it. Does the aspx file need to be a specific encoding?

Comment: Just curious if all those files have proper encoding (UTF-8). Setting such encoding won't do any damage, can only help you so try it.

Comment: Just checked. The aspx file has utf-8 encoding

Answer (score 1):

The charset: 'UTF-8' settings is good, however you need to set the `<meta/>` tag in the HTML code like so:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html"; charset="UTF-8">
<div class="my-class">Power, speed, style —&nbsp;James Bond’s 10&nbsp;greatest drives</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `encoding` parameter. If `UTF8` won't work then try `UTF-8`.

```
var settings = {mode: 'w', charset: 'UTF-8', encoding: 'UTF8'};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the error is the same after trying all combinations of `UTF8` and `UTF-8` on `charset` and `encoding`. Is this completely even a character encoding issue? As it is strange that it is replacing `&nbsp;` which has no special characters. It somehow recognizes that as an html entity and I guess attempts to replace it with a space.

Comment: That is weird. Maybe it's phantomjs bug? You should post that question on their github too.

Comment: `&nbsp;` is a "non-breaking space", so, yes, it will show as a space.

Comment: @RickJames It isn't about how it displays though. It is what the html content of the element is. If I run `document.querySelectorAll('.my-class')[0].innerHTML` in the console on the actual site, then it will display `&nbsp;` as that is the html

Answer (score 0):

Is `&` an operator in phantomJS?

Line these up:

```
style —&nbsp;James Bond’s 10&nbsp;greatest
   style ΓÇö James BondΓÇÖs 10 greatest
```

I suggest that the "emdash" (`—`) and the quote (`’`) are the villains, not `&nbsp;`.  nbsp = non-breaking space, which views as a space, but prevents a line break.

Conclusion:  UTF-8 characters are not properly recognized in phantomJS.

`ΓÇÖ` is hex `CE93C387C396` (assuming utf8 encoding), but that hex does not then map into anything recognizable.  (I pursued this path because a common problem is for an encoding to be misinterpreted, leading to mangling.)  Also, since `ΓÇÖ` is a mixture of Greek and Latin, it cannot be correctly interpreted in a single character set other than UTF-8.

Where did the "data" come from?  Perhaps the mangling occurred *before* phantomJS.

Comment: This is just returning the innerHTML of an element though. It shouldn't be interpreting it in any way. The data is coming from our CMS, but it displays correctly on the real page, but then when phantomJS retrieves it, then it is garbled

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @tic for asking a question that actually provided me a solution :).

I was converting a html statement to pdf using phantomJs's rasterize.js example. However some unicode characters are being rendered as garbage. See snapshot 1 where the Indian currency symbol (locale: 'en-IN', currency: INR) is rendered incorrectly.

After adding the meta tag (to the head tag) suggested by @tic and then the pdf started showing the characters as expected.

Please note, the meta tag is optional in chrome, meaning even without the meta tag I was able to see the symbols when browsing the html page directly in browser. The problem was when rendering as a pdf/png.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Before: (messed up currency symbols)

[image]

After: (proper currency symbols)

[image]